# Tail-calls corrupted when compiled with __attribute__((musttail))

Tags: c, clang, tail-call-optimization, tail-call

I was working a Lisp interpreter with a 'threaded' design, where it compiles to a VM where each instruction is a C function that calls the next instruction — if the compiler does tail call elimination, then it should only need a `jmp` between instructions.

It's a stack-oriented VM, with an `Imm` instructions that pushes an immediate to the stack.

When I manually call the first `Imm` instruction, it runs fine.  However, once the `Imm` instruction jumps to the next `Imm` instruction, it seems the call stack becomes corrupted as none of the parameter values are valid anymore.  However, this *only* occurs when I use clang with `__attribute__((musttail))`.  In fact, `gcc -O3` and even `clang -O3` compile it to a `jmp` just fine (but clang without musttail compiles to a call).  Anyone know what could be going on here?

A stripped-down version of the code that exhibits this behavior follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef enum { TypeInt = 0 } Tag;

typedef struct {
    int n; /* item count */
    int64_t *val; /* pointer */
} List;

typedef struct Block {
    struct Ins *ins;
    int n;
    struct Fn *fn;
    struct Scope *locals;
    struct Scope *mod;
} Block;

typedef struct Scope {
    int n;
    const char **names;
    int64_t *vals;
    Block first;
} Scope;

typedef struct Ins {
    char (*op)(int, Block);
    int64_t imm;
} Ins;

typedef struct Fn {
    Scope locals;
    Scope *mod;
} Fn;


int64_t *stack;
uint32_t sc; /* stack counter */
uint32_t fc; /* frame counter */
uint32_t cap = 128 * sizeof(int64_t);

#define F_INS(x) char x(int ic, Block b)
#define MUSTTAIL __attribute__((musttail))
#define INSRET MUSTTAIL return b.ins[ic + 1].op(ic + 1, b);

#define N_BUILTINS 1
const char *builtins[N_BUILTINS] = { "+" };

void vm_init(void) { stack = malloc(cap); }
F_INS(Done) { return 0; }

void stack_push(int64_t v)
{
    if (++sc >= cap) stack = realloc(stack, cap *= 2);
    stack[sc - 1] = v;
}

F_INS(Imm)
{
    printf("IC: %u\n", ic);
    stack_push(b.ins[ic].imm);
    INSRET;
}

F_INS(Add)
{
    int64_t y = stack[--sc];
    int64_t x = stack[--sc];
    stack_push(x + y);
    INSRET;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Block b = {0};
    vm_init();
    b.ins = realloc(b.ins, ++b.n * sizeof(Ins));
    b.ins[b.n - 1].op = &Imm;
    b.ins[b.n - 1].imm = 3;
    b.ins = realloc(b.ins, ++b.n * sizeof(Ins));
    b.ins[b.n - 1].op = &Imm;
    b.ins[b.n - 1].imm = 4;
    b.ins = realloc(b.ins, ++b.n * sizeof(Ins));
    b.ins[b.n - 1].op = &Add;
    b.ins = realloc(b.ins, ++b.n * sizeof(Ins));
    b.ins[b.n - 1].op = &Done;

    (*b.ins[0].op)(0, b);
}
```

When I remove the structs for `Fn` and `Scope`, or when I turn optimizations on, it doesn't crash anymore.  Bizarrely, it works fine with `fsanitize=memory`.

The full code is at [https://git.sr.ht/~euclaise/trent/tree/](https://git.sr.ht/%7Eeuclaise/trent/tree/)

```
clang version 14.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, clang is doing the jump just fine with or without musttail.

Comment: @n.m. Hmm, very odd.  Are you using clang 14.0.6?  It seems it does jump fine, but the `b` values end up zeroed.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/s7bGbTn8s

Comment: @n.m. https://godbolt.org/z/xajTWv5eW

Your version has `__clang` instead of `__clang__` (I later edited it to be unconditional)

Comment: Not a lot of difference https://godbolt.org/z/Mc47G8MvE The problem actually happens only with optimisations off.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out as much